While upgrading jar files Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
I have been facing this issue from few days now. If you can help me understand how to solve this problem, it would be greatly appreciated. This is a pretty old project working on Java 1.8, JSF Prime faces, Maven 3.1 and Wildfly 13. There was lot of security issues, so we were upgrading few jar files.
Below is the complete error log.

    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:92)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:602)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:300)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:140)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:584)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:555)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:597)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more

10:29:51,740 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "CactusServer.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./CactusServer" => "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"},
    "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"CactusServer.war\".deploymentCompleteService"],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => [
            "jboss.clustering.web.route.default-server",
            "jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa",
            "jboss.txn.service.remote",
            "jboss.xts.handlers",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.default-service-provider-registry.ejb",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.default-service-provider-registry.web",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.ejb.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.hibernate.entity",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.hibernate.local-query",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.hibernate.timestamps",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.server.client-mappings",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.server.default",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.web.client-mappings",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.web.default-server",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.group.web.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.ejb.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.server.default",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry.web.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.ejb.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.hibernate.entity",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.hibernate.local-query",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.hibernate.timestamps",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.server.client-mappings",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.server.default",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.web.client-mappings",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.web.default-server",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-entry.web.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.ejb.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.hibernate.entity",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.hibernate.local-query",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.hibernate.timestamps",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.server.client-mappings",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.server.default",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.web.client-mappings",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.web.default-server",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.registry-factory.web.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.ejb.client-mappings",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.ejb.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.hibernate.entity",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.hibernate.local-query",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.hibernate.timestamps",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.server.client-mappings",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.server.default",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.web.client-mappings",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.web.default-server",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.cache.service-provider-registry.web.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.ejb",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.hibernate",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.local",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.server",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.command-dispatcher-factory.web",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.default-command-dispatcher-factory",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.group.hibernate",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.group.server",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.group.web",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.ejb.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.hibernate.entity",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.hibernate.local-query",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.hibernate.timestamps",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.server.client-mappings",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.server.default",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.hibernate.entity",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.hibernate.local-query",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.hibernate.timestamps",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.server.default",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.store.web.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.web.client-mappings",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.web.default-server",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.web.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity.expiration",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity.locking",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity.memory",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.entity.transaction",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.expiration",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.locking",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.memory",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.local-query.transaction",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.expiration",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.locking",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.memory",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.hibernate.timestamps.transaction",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.client-mappings",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.expiration",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.locking",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.memory",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.server.default.transaction",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.client-mappings",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.default-server",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.expiration",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.locking",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.memory",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.transaction",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.web.passivation.write",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.hibernate",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.server",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.web",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.hibernate",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.hibernate.transport",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.server",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.server.transport",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.web",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.web.transport",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache.ejb",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache.web",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache-configuration.server",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache-configuration.web"
        ]
    }
}

Upgrading all the jars of application which have vulnerabilities. This project has different modules/projects which has six different project with six different pom files.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
